# Obtaining in IE the length of a Java array passed from an applet to its Javascript wrapper

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, applet

I have the following method in my applet:

```
public File[] getFiles()
```

Which I call from Javascript as follows:

```
var files = applet.getFiles();

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // Do something.
}
```

This works in Firefox but IE gives me

```
'length' is null or not an object
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Knowing nothing about Java I can only ask if you've tried "for(i in files) { /* do stuff */ }"

Comment: Don't you mean File[] (not Files[])? Other then that, it would help if you alert(files). Also, if you have a javascript debugger (DebugBar, for example) that would help the most.

Comment: @annakata: Yes, I've tried it.  It doesn't work in either Firefox or IE.

@laginimaineb: Corrected question.  Thanks!  Also, alert(files) doesn't help much but I'm going to try kizzx2's suggestion below to peek into files' structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work-around found.  Instead of returning an array, return a list instead.  Then iterate through it using the get and size methods.  Works in both IE and Firefox.

So, the applet method should be:

```
public List<File> getFiles()
```

And to use it Javascript-side:

```
var files = applet.getFiles();
for (var i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    // Do something with files.get(i).
}
```

Comment: Should have checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en/LiveConnect first.  Clearly stated there that arrays are dodgy in a certain LiveConnect version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) in IE to investigate what's going on with `files`

First, include Firebug Lite in your file

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
    src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>
```

Now log it in the console with

```
var files = applet.getFiles();
console.log(files);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) //...
```

Now you can investigate what object was actually being returned by `getFiles()`

I give this suggestion because IE said *`length` is null not or not an object* instead of *`files` is null or not an object*, so maybe `files` have other methods that you can use. Use Firebug to reflect those.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how widely supported passing a Java array to javascript is. A workaround is to return the array as a delimited string as shown in the following example

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0183.html

Comment: Already seen this link.  Approach is not viable since getFiles returns an array of non-string objects.

Comment: I realise that, you build the string from the string attributes required from the File array, eg. the file path.
you can then get the details required from the file using that path